# java NullPointerException with LocationManager

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, locationmanager

I am building an Android App which uses LocationManager to get the latitude and longitude from the users, then enters those variables into a URL, which opens in a WebView.

For some reason, on some Android devices and my Eclipse Emulator, the app crashes when this activity tries to open. I get a NPE error in my crash report.

I have pinned down the error to the following two lines of code:

```
double longitude = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
double latitude = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
```

When I set those two variables as static values, like 1, the app runs correctly.

Below is my full page1.activity. Can anyone help?

```
package com.xxx.yyy;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;
import com.xxx.yyy.R;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.ISideNavigationCallback;
import com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView;

public class page1 extends MainActivity implements ISideNavigationCallback, GeolocationPermissions.Callback {

    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.extra.MTGOBJECT";
    public static final String EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID = "com.devspark.sidenavigation.sample.extra.RESOURCE_ID";

    private ImageView icon;
    private SideNavigationView sideNavigationView;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
        sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.side_navigation_menu);
        sideNavigationView.setMenuClickCallback(this);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_TITLE)) {
            String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
            int resId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, 0);
            setTitle(title);
            icon.setImageResource(resId);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Get webview layout
         WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

         //loading
         mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Finding locations near you");



         engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                 @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                 {


                 }
         });


         engine.setWebViewClient(new FixedWebViewClient() {
                 @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
                 {
                     findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                 }

                 @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){ 

                     findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(view.GONE);

                     if(mProgress.isShowing()) { 
                         mProgress.dismiss();  }

               //error handeling     
                 }
                 @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    try {
                        webView.stopLoading();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        webView.clearView();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html"); //background to message dialog, or page you want to load if requested page is offline
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(page1.this).create(); //remove these 4 rules if you load an assets page instead.
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("No internet connection was found!");
                    alertDialog.setButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           finish();
                           startActivity(getIntent());
                       }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                    super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }

         });

         LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
         Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
              };

            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
            // Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

            Location lastKnownLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

            double longitude = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
            double latitude = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();

         engine.loadUrl("http://www.turn2clients.com/app/home/iPhone/dev/?s=&geo-radius=3&geo=on&geo-lat="+latitude+"&geo-lng="+longitude+"&categories=0&locations=0&dir-search=yes");
         //if you would like to load local assets file, replace with file:///android_asset/error.html


 }

    public void invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember) {

    }

    final class GeoClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
    Callback callback) {
    }

    }




 private class FixedWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 view.loadUrl(url);

                 //start a new application/activity (in this case youtube) if url starts with 
                if (url.startsWith("mlb")){

                 return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 view.loadUrl(url);

                 return true;
         }
         }

 }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
            Intent page1 = new Intent(this, page1.class);     
            startActivity(page1);
            break;

        case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
            Intent page2 = new Intent(this, page2.class);     
            startActivity(page2);
            break;

        case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item3:
            Intent page3 = new Intent(this, page3.class);     
            startActivity(page3);
            break;

        default:
            return;
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //This part will close you app if a certain url is visited, ofcourse you can replace this with any other action.
        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String url = engine.getUrl(); 
        if (url.equals("http://closeifthisurlisvisited.com/") ||
                url.equals("http://alsocloseifthisurlisvisited.com")) {
                // exit
                super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
                // Go back when back button is pressed
                engine.goBack();
        }
        //thats it
        // hide menu if it shown with backbutton
        if (sideNavigationView.isShown()) {
            sideNavigationView.hideMenu();
        } else {
            //super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start activity from SideNavigation.
     * 
     * @param title
     *            title of Activity
     * @param resId
     *            resource if of background image
     */
    private void invokeActivity(String title, int resId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, resId);

        // all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this
        // Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
        // new Intent.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(intent);
        // no animation of transition
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is not "last known location", you should wait until the location manager calculate it. It doesn't always happen, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use location services by CWAC Location Poller service is already made for us to use it just you have to give the time interval to wake up it

Do it like dis way n you'll need the jar file which you can get it from [here]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pgxk2v9l5vl0h2j/3svyZnuwOK/CWAC-LocationPoller.jar

From your activity start LocationPoller and set the alarm repeating to the time you want

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
LocationPollerParameter parameter = new LocationPollerParameter(bundle);
parameter.setIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion(new Intent(this,
        LocationReceiver.class));
// try GPS and fall back to NETWORK_PROVIDER
parameter.setProviders(new String[] { LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER });
parameter.setTimeout(120000);
i.putExtras(bundle);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 300000, pi);
```

Make a receiver class Location Receiver from where you'll fetch the lat n lon

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    try {      
      Bundle b=intent.getExtras();

      LocationPollerResult locationResult = new LocationPollerResult(b);

      Location loc=locationResult.getLocation();
      String msg;

      if (loc==null) {
        loc=locationResult.getLastKnownLocation();

        if (loc==null) {
          msg=locationResult.getError();
        }
        else {
          msg="TIMEOUT, lastKnown="+loc.toString();
        }
      }
      else {
        msg=loc.toString();



        Log.i("Location Latitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
        Log.i("Location Longitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
        Log.i("Location Accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));




      }

      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "received location: " + msg);   



    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

and add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller" />

   <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService" />
```

and the receiver declaration where you'll fetch everything

```
<receiver android:name="com.RareMediaCompany.Helios.LocationReceiver" />
```